# Testing if two directory trees overlap

Tags: bash, shell-script, find

Let `$foo` and `$bar` be two absolute directory names (output by `realpath`). I want to test if either is contained in the other one, at any depth, and execute commands accordingly.

I thought I'd use `find`, but its exit status doesn't tell whether something has been found or not. So I've come to:

```
if [ x$(find -H "$foo" -path "$bar" -printf y -quit) == xy \
    -o x$(find -H "$bar" -path "$foo" -printf y -quit) == xy ] ; then
    ...
fi
```

Is it correct? Is there something simpler?

Context: my home dir contains an encrypted folder (ecryptfs). I'm writing a script that will sync its argument to the cloud. I don't want the decrypted files to be synced, so I'll test whether the argument overlaps the encrypted folder to unmount the ecryptfs before syncing.

Comment: I don't understand. When you have 2 full (realpath) paths they can't contain eachother as they are absolute. Do you mean: Share a common parent folder?

Comment: What are you looking for?: a tree being a sub-tree of another?; a tree being a sub-tree of another, but having a different name, because of sys-links?; a tree having a copy of part of another tree?; a tree containing a part of another tree because of bind mounts etc?; something else?

Comment: Can't you just ignore the mounted directory with your script? How does the script sync the files?

Comment: @Johan I'm searching if _either_ is contained in the other one (it could be foo under bar or bar under foo)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor a tree being a sub-tree of another

Comment: @Kusalananda I don't want to ignore it, I want to take specific action: unmounting the ecryptfs before sync so that the crypted version gets synced (I'm mounting the ecryptfs folder on itself: crypted and uncrypted files are in the same place)

Comment: So, the sync script could do that.

Comment: @Kusalananda I don't understand what you mean. I am writing this very script (see question). Not only it "could" do that, but it _should_, because I require it to ;) The syncing itself is done by a single command (rclone sync ...)

Comment: Oh, ok. I just did not se an `umount` command in there...

Comment: When you say “a tree being a sub-tree of another” do you mean: a tree being a sub-tree of another?; a tree being a sub-tree of another, but having a different name, because of sys-links?; a tree having a copy of part of another tree?; a tree containing a part of another tree because of bind mounts etc?; something else?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor answers to your questions: yes/IDK/no/no/no. What are sys-links? (Symlinks are out the way thanks to realpath.) A copy of a dir is not the dir itself. "Tree" like in "tree graph" (no binds).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question and the context. But maybe this works:

```sh
foo="$(realpath "...")"
bar="$(realpath "...")"

if [[ $foo = $bar/* || $bar = $foo/* ]]; then
    echo "Overlap"
fi
```

Note that this won't work if one tree is sym-linked into the other.

Comment: If I understand the original question correct, `$foo` and `$bar` should already be results from `realpath`, so you could use `$foo` and `$bar` directly instead of `$rd1` and `$rd2`

Comment: @Bodo You are right, updated.

Comment: Excellent! I didn't know that idiom. I think I need a `/` before the `*`, right? Also, man bash says there is no word splitting inside `[[ ]]`, could I drop the double quotes there?

Comment: Good catch! Yes, the `/` is needed. The quotes are not needed. I always follow: if in doubt: quote. I'll update.

Comment: @Ralf thanks! I follow the same rule, but in an answer I think it's better to be as accurate as possible. I also did some tests about the quotes in `foo="$(...)"`. The man is not very explicit about word splitting of the result of `$()`; I understand this result _may_ be split according to the context, hence there is no word splitting here because variable assignments do not induce word splitting. Thanks again!

Comment: It also won't detect bind mounts, won't distinguish same names but different directories. This is no fault of the answer, as the question is not well specified.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor same absolute paths but different directories? I can admit my question is ill-specified, but how often do you encounter bind mounts in home directories?